# What is support of beta distribution?

Tags: beta-distribution

I do know that the probability density function of beta distribution is 
$$
\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}} {\displaystyle \mathrm {B}(\alpha,\beta)}\!
$$
where 
$$
{\displaystyle \mathrm {B} (\alpha ,\beta )={\frac {\Gamma (\alpha )\Gamma (\beta )}{\Gamma (\alpha +\beta )}}}
$$

Also, I know that support of a function is the subset of the domain containing those elements which are not mapped to zero. But I don't know how do I go about calculating the support for beta distribution.

Comment: What values of the density would you get if either $x$ or $1-x$ were negative??

Comment: In addition to @whuber, have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2355251/614436

Comment: Also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).